Resolve svn Error: "Can't set properties on 'path/to/somefolder': invalid status for updating properties."
When doing a merge in subversion, I get this error:

Error: Can't set properties on 'path/to/somefolder': invalid status for updating properties.

The merge deletes the folder (it moved it to another location). There was only one file contained within.
TortoiseSVN gives me an option to "Continue Merge" but gives the same error on the same directory.
How can I resolve this?

I'm using a fully recursive checkout. In TortoiseSVN: Merge, "specific range" (with no range given), Fully Recursive.

I reverted my merge, found the revision that removed that file, and merged that revision first. Committed that and then tried the merge again and didn't get the error.
Not sure why svn doesn't handle that as part of the merge, but it worked.
